# Bash - nested while loop: write txt file lines to csv

Tags: bash

My bash script retrieves a list of folders, and stores them under a projectlist parameter.

Later, I want to loop through each folder, using the project name as a variable in the file path. Each project folder contains a ProjectFile.txt file, from which I want to append the contents to a common .csv file.

```
projectlist=$(./some/project/filepath/projects)

echo ${projectlist[@]}

while read project;
do

    while read line;
    do
        echo "$project" "$line" >> /data/allData.csv
    done < ./some/project/filepath/projects/"$project"/ProjectFile.txt

done < $projectlist
```

What it currently ends up doing however, is printing each individual element in the projectlist, without writing anything to the .csv file. Any idea where the issue lies?

Comment: `projectlist`, as defined here, is not an array.

Comment: It's also not a file name, so `<` isn't appropriate. You would use `<<<` instead,

Comment: On line 1 $(...) runs a command, and you supply a directory.

Comment: to  use the syntax `${projectlist[@]}` you  need an array. To create an an array, you use `projectlist=( $( cmd ) )` .Good luck.

Comment: The `;` are all useless and should be removed.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the array creation, will the filepath as cmd be valid? Or should I use filepath -l, or something?